# Routing on same network to different interface

Tags: routing

Our network consists of a fixed assigned IP address per machine that connects to the domain. One machine (Windows 2003) has a wireless router connected to it (still on domain) with internet traffic routed through the wireless router, and network domain routed through domain.

I need to route my machine's internet traffic through this Windows 2003 machine so I can jump through the wireless connection.

Is this possible?

I've tried adding a route on my machine to the IP address of the Windows 2003 server, for internet traffic, but this assumes I'm still on the domain?

**[Update]**

More information might be required

My IP is 11.1.89.120

The Windows 2003 server IP is 11.1.89.34

Wireless Router IP is 47.123.34.34

I need to route all traffic from my IP address, for 152.1.1.34 through 11.1.89.34 which routes all traffic out to 47.123.34.34.

I don't need to worry about 47.123.x.x traffic as this is already set up. I've tried setting a route (route add 152.1.1.34 mask 255.255.255.255 11.1.84.34) but this does not work :(.

**[Update 2]**

I successfully traced my route to the Windows 2003 server using a tool to monitor traffic from a given source (11.1.89.120). But I still get a DNS lookup, if I try and browse to Google.com or Microsoft.com (testing) from my machine. First I thought it's a Firewall issue, but firewall has been disabled on our network for testing? I cannot use Routing and Remote Access (application in Win2003) as the machine is used for other routing as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want a default route (0.0.0.0) i suspect

> route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 11.1.84.34

by default the default route already has a metric of 25, if you add a route with anything 'lower' than this, then it will have a higher priority

Comment: Hi BoyMars, adding a default route (0.0.0.0) will force me to remove the current default on the same range as they'll clash, no? The route on default fails on DNS lookup, assuming that either a firewall is blocking incoming traffic, or internet shared connections has not been enabled?

Comment: but thats what you wanted... to route all traffic, it doesnt matter if it replaces the exiting one or not, provided the metric is lower, this is the route which will be used - can you explain what you mean by 'the route on default fails on DNS lookup'? i might be going about this the wrong way, why dont you simply make the server your gateway?

Comment: dns lookup failed is a misleading error message from windows if i try and browse a web site. it's simply not hitting web site. basically, i need to route internet traffic through the wireless router connected to server, and all domain services, like network folders and intranet through the normal domain. this i can set up no problem, but my problem is trying to tell server that any traffic coming in from my ip address (11.1.89.120) should be pushed through to 47.123.x.x. making it my gateway might work, haven't tried that :$

Comment: what is your gateway at the moment? is it another router? it sounds like you'd be better using your win2003 server as a proxy (transparent) and block the internet (if not already) from your current gateway/router.

Comment: current gateway is defined by corporate network. i've tried targeting the server by manually assigning IP, sub-net and gateway but this caused issues with me being on the domain. i'm missing something very silly here. will try transparency on the connection. thanks